# Deserializing dynamic object JSON,Net

Tags: c#, json.net, sqlkata

I have two applications:
The first one gets data from the database using SqlKata and then serializes it using Newtonsoft and saves it to a file
ex:

```
  SqlServerCompiler compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
                QueryFactory queryFactory = new QueryFactory(MyConnection,compiler);
                 var data = queryFactory.Query("tblName").Where("ID",1).First();
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                StreamWriter writer = new ...
                writer.write(json);
```

this works fine and the json file is created with the data within it
 The second application reads the JSON file, deserializes it and then add it to the database
    ex:

```
  using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:/MyFile")){
    string temp = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var toInsert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(temp);
    //note that i dont have a class that represents the structure of the deserialized object,thus i should catch it dynamically
    queryFactory.Query("tblName").Insert(toInsert);
}
```

> The insertion throws an exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Parameter Count
>   Mismatch'

knowing that the database table is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you donot have a class, you can use **dynamic** type. A dynamic type escapes type checking at compile time; instead, it resolves type at run time.

Try this:

```
 var toInsert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(temp);
```

Comment: if I do that,the queryFactory.Query("tblName").Insert(toInsert) will throw an error

Comment: error:Query has no applicable method name 'Insert' but appears to have an extenstion method by that name,Consider Casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extenstion method without the extension method syntax

Comment: Can you share what is expected in `toInsert`?

Comment: its expected to have  data for a row of the structure of tblName.but I only have the structure of tblName in the database,i dont have a corresponding class for it

Comment: You can try this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(temp);`. If it doesn't work, it's better to loop through the object and create `toInsert ` dynamically as required

Comment: same result :parameter count mismatch